# Using DBContext to Select Fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

I've got a couple questions regarding DBContext and achieveing my desired Results. 
I can retrieve data like this

```
---Model
   public class InvoiceModel
{
    [Key]
    public int? Invoice_Number { get; set; }
    public decimal Amt_Total { get; set; }
    public decimal Amt_Due { get; set; }
    public decimal Amt_Paid { get; set; }

    public List<InvoiceModel> GetInvoice()
    {
        using (VuittonEntities db = new VuittonEntities())
        {
            return (from inv in db.Invoice
                    select new InvoiceModel
                    {
                        Invoice_Number = inv.Invoice_,
                        Amt_Total = inv.AmountTotal,
                        Amt_Due = inv.AmountDue,
                        Amt_Paid = inv.AmountPaid
                    }).ToList();
        }
    }

--- Controller
public ViewResult Index()
    {
      var data = new InvoiceModel().GetInvoice();
      return View(data);
    }
```

This is pretty much standard LinQ and it returns my Invoice table with the 4 fields I selected. But now I want to achieve this using DB Context. So I added this new Class to my controller and called it in the view like this.

```
 Controller 
public class VuittonEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<InvoiceModel> Invoice { get; set; }
    }
 View
   public ViewResult Index()
    {
          VuittonEntities db = new VuittonEntities();       
          return View(db.Invoice.ToList());
    }
```

It returns the Entire table and I have to comment out my List'InvoiceModel' class

Assumptions:
VuittonEntities is my Connection String Name,
Invoice is the table
Vuitton is my .edmx class --
I heard that this can be achieved without having to use a Select Statement. It appears I am not linking my model class to a LinQ entity but when I add my context class, it throws errors on my inv."FieldName" columns in my List{InvoiceModel} Class.

TLDR Version: 
How Can I return selected fields from DbContext Class instead of entire table 
Why does adding a DBContext class raise errors on my List(ModelClass) fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the entire table, then don't just call `ToList()` on the `DbSet`, as that will just grab all of the table as you have seen..  You had it right when using `Select`, since the Select statement is meant to create a projection from one set of data into a new form (new class, model, anonymous object).

Comment: Ok, I was told a select statement is not necessary but there is another way, any idea on this? Also, can you shed light on the reason why my List class errors, when I add a DbContext Class?

Comment: Only way I could think of it working without a `Select` off the top of my head, is by using a SQL view, and mapping the view in your DbContext...  I would probably end up sticking with the Select though..  Also, if you want help with the error, you gotta say what the error is!  Finally, I would seriously consider separating some of your logic up, like the GetInvoice method INSIDE the InvoiceModel class - that should really be elsewhere, like in a service layer or repository.  Finally, your Key shouldn't be nullable for your entity stored in the database.

Comment: your right I should not have that nullable column, I have an ID field which  i  will use instead. My inv."field" points towards my entity tabel, but when I throw in the DB Context field, it points towards my model class instead. I was planning on moving it out into a data layer, I wanted to get this working before I added another step, I'm gonna try that now and see what happens.